# Setting messages from classes in Drupal

Tags: 8

How do we set messages now in 8.x? Do we still use drupal_set_message? Not a fan of mixing procedural calls within classes if it can be avoided.

Comment: You could define/create your own service and put the drupal_set_message() inside of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to 8.5.x, `drupal_set_message` is the way.

For >=8.5.0-alpha1, there's a [new messenger service](https://www.drupal.org/node/2774931), with a note (and example which I won't bother copying):

> The procedural functions drupal_set_message() and drupal_get_messages() have been deprecated and replaced with a dedicated Messenger service.
>
> You should now inject this service as a dependency for your own services and controllers:

Answer (score 0):

Interesting post by Clive, I didn't know about 8.5 having a new messaging service. That's great.

In the meantime, I add the call in a protected method of the class:

```
protected function sendMessage($message, $type = 'success') {
  drupal_set_message($message, $type);
}
```

While it is still calling a static function from a class, the advantage is that when doing unit tests, this method can be overridden, so that tests are not broken.